# C# Console App - Remove lines in list that start with string

Tags: c#, list, csv, console-application

I've got a method to read a simple CSV file into an IList, which I'll then use to do some querying and work with the data, later writing some things to another file. I've managed to read the data into this list, making sure to skip any null or empty/whitespace lines, but I have a problem: About every 200 records (and this is not EXACT, it could be a little early or later,) I have a header row that was written to the CSV file. I need to make sure to SKIP reading that header row (that starts with the string "Name" in Column 1) when putting this data into my IList. That header row could appear multiple times in the data source, so I need to make sure I'm checking each row in this method as it reads the data into the list, and have it skip any "header" row/row that starts with "Name" in Column 1.

My code for reading the data into the List is below. Any suggestions? I'm not able to really control the CSV file I need to read from, so the cleanup and ignoring of this row needs to be done as I'm reading the data into my program.

```
    string path2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string csvPath = path2 + "\\" + "AleksReport.csv";

    public static IList<string> ReadFile(string csvPath)
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();

        return (from line in File.ReadAllLines(csvPath)
                where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)
                let columns = line.Split(',')
                where columns.Length >= 2 &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columns[0]) &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columns[1]) &&
                select line).ToList();


    }
```

Comment: I suggest using CSVHelper instead of trying to parse it manually.  CSV is a lot more complex than "split on commas"

Comment: Just for your information, your code will not work with CSV that have commas inside values, like this:

`"value with ,",value with no comma`

Comment: How about `where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && !line.StartsWith("Name")`?

Comment: Shouldn't the header be the very first line? Reading first line, remembering it and skipping any similar line later shouldn't be a hard problem.

Comment: @Amy I'd be open to that, but I'm still going to need to work with the same source file, that has a "header row" appearing about every 200 records. Would you have any suggestions on what the code should look like using CSVHelper?

Comment: @LoganSBishop CSVHelper has some excellent documentation and tutorials.  I suggest giving it a try.  Are the headers every 200 records the same headers or different?  Put differently, is each set of 200 records the same dataset?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've tried that, alas, every 200 records I still have the header row appearing in my data.

Comment: @Amy Yes, every set of 200 records is the same dataset. Currently, when taking my list and writing it to another results file (after I do any data operations on it I need to) I'm still getting that "header" row about every 200 rows. The original data source is a CSV file that's pulled from a URL-RPC gateway and written--but I have to work with this data after that.

Comment: @LoganSBishop Something like this [CSVHelper: Reading multiple data sets](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-multiple-data-sets/).  So what you can do is treat each header+rows as a separate dataset, despite them being "the same".

Comment: The solution to your problem might come faster to you if you reduce your query into separate small steps. You'll be able so see things more clearly, like, as the one fellow said above, commas within your delimited columns. Once you've done that, you can rebuild your query. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like, through some of the comments--I figured out my issue! Managed to take care of this by doing a string compare on each Line when I write the file back to my results dataset, after doing my queries and data transformation. I can safely ignore the rows I don't need to worry about. It does involve a quick extra read/write function, but it's so trivial!

I can't believe I was silly enough to overlook something this basic. Thanks everyone!